# Grid of buttons in two columns using pysimplegui

Tags: python

I can generate a 10x10 grid of buttons in pysimplegui with no problem, but I am looking to set up 2 grids that are side by side in my layout.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('Dark Blue 3')
MAX_ROWS = MAX_COL = 10


layout =   [[sg.Text('menu', font='Default 25')],
           [sg.Text(size=(15,1), key='-MESSAGE-', font='Default 20')]]

layout +=  [[sg.Button(str('O'), size=(4, 2), pad=(0,0), border_width=0, key=(row,col)) for col in range(MAX_COL)] for row in range(MAX_ROWS)]

layout +=  [[sg.Button('Exit', button_color=('white', 'red'))]]

window = sg.Window('menu', layout)

while True:         # The Event Loop
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event, values)
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            break
        if event in position:           # simulate a hit or a miss
            window[event].update('H', button_color=('white','red'))
            window['-MESSAGE-'].update('Hit')
        else:
            window[event].update('M', button_color=('white','black'))
            window['-MESSAGE-'].update('Miss')
window.close()
```

My basic layout is below and just want it repeated in a second column beside the orignal.

I keep getting an error saying the grid is being viewed as a list rather than an element when I try add it to a column view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using function to generate two same layouts, but with different keys for same elements.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def grids(index):
    return [[sg.Button(str('O'), size=(4, 2), pad=(0,0), border_width=0, key=(index, row,col)) for col in range(MAX_COL)] for row in range(MAX_ROWS)]

sg.theme('Dark Blue 3')
MAX_ROWS = MAX_COL = 10
layout = [[sg.Column(grids(0)), sg.Column(grids(1))]]
sg.Window('Title', layout).read(close=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That works like a charm and the event readings I'm getting are perfect for working between the two grids. really appreciate the help